# How can I grow the height of a function letter to match the height of the parameters?

Tags: math-mode, height, parameters

I'm only an occasional LaTeX user, and ever more rare math mode user, so maybe this is simple for others, but not for me:

I have a function named `L*`, and it has a fraction as parameter. In my first attempt (`$L*\left(\frac{X}{X_N}\right)$`) it looked as if I wanted to multiply `L` with the parameter, so I changed it to `${L*}\left(\frac{X}{X_N}\right)$`.

[image: Formula L*(X/Xn)]

Still in my eyes it looks like a multiplication (can I reduce the spacing between `*` and `(`?), so I want the size of `L*` match the height of the parameter, like this:

[image: Formula L*(X/Xn) with larger L*]

(As any TeX-eye can see I faked the size by using an image editor).

What I did try without success was a `\left{L*}\frac{...}{...}` which is not allowed, however.

Finally: When answering remember: Simple problems should have simple answers to be efficient.  If the  answer looks overly complicated (makes the formular very unreadable, I probably will not accept it.

Comment: My 0.02ct: This is kind of scaling is unusual (you mentioned that you typeset mathematics rarely). One question: "If the answer looks overly complicated ..." does that mean you use only software and operating systems whose code you know and understand? Almost anybody can hide code in a LaTeX package.

Comment: Shouldn't the asterisk be positioned as superscript to disambiguate?

Comment: @Bernard: Good point; I didn't look closely when copying the formula. Unfortunately it's not really related to an answer to this question.

Comment: If you want **exactly** the same size, you could define lengths for the function name and parameters, render inside `\savebox`, take the heights of both with `\settoheight`, divide to get a ratio, and then expand the box on the lect with a `\scalebox`.`

Comment: Hint: Even if you don't accept an answer, you can still show appreciation by upvoting if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a ***very bad idea***.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Lstar}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$L{*}$}%
  \sbox2{$#1$}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2>1.5\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
    \vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{!}{0.8\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2}{\box0}}}%
  \else
    L{*}%
  \fi
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Lstar{(x)}+\Lstar{\left(\frac{X}{X_N}\right)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The idea may be bad, but it's what I had asked for ;-)

Comment: Trying to understand the answer, I wonder about the two factors `1.5` and `0.8`: It seems you adjust the `L*` only of the height of the parameter is 1.5 times the height of `L*`, and then you don't scale it to 100% of the parameter's size, but to 80%. Right?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, that's right. Adjust to suit, if you *really* want to pursue this endeavor.

Answer (score 3):

By default `*` is a binary operator so it has extra space put around it to make it look like multiplication. You can remove this space by enclosing it in braces: `{*}`. You could also use `\ast` instead of `*`, but this doesn't help because, as far as I can see, they are equivalent.

If you want to have a larger asterisk then you need to "leave" math-mode and change the font size. If you are going to do this often then I suggest using a macro like

```
\newcommand\Ast{\mbox{\large${\ast}$}}
```

Using these different options gives the following output:

[image]

From the OP, I suspect that the last option, which uses the macro above, is what you want. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Ast{\mbox{\large${\ast}$}}
\newcommand\Xn{\bigl(\frac{X}{X_N}\bigr)}

\begin{document}

  $L*\Xn$

  $L\ast\Xn$

  $L{*}\Xn$

  $L{\ast}\Xn$

  $L\Ast\Xn$

\end{document}
```

Btw, please always post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) with your questions so that people know what you are doing. This makes it easier for people to help you and decreases the chance that they will solve a "different problem" than what you are asking.

Comment: Isn't there a simple solution that can scale the height of `L*` to the same height as the `\left(`? Could I do something like `\left{L}\left{*}\left(...` (`\left{L*}` doesn't work) without corresponding `\right` parts?

Comment: @U. Windl For me, the proposed solution seems pretty simple.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `\bigl(` and `\left(`?

Comment: @U.Windl Strangely enough there doesnt seem to be a TeX.SX question on this. The short version is that the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package provides commands `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl`,  `\bigm`, `\Bigm`, `\biggm`,  `\Biggm`  `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, `\biggr`, `\Biggr` to give finer control over the sizes of delimiters. I often find that `\left(...\right)` gives delimiters that are too big and that I can get delimiter sizes that I like using these commands.